# How to remember "capo" in figurative sense?

Tags: vocabulary, homograph

I am confused by the word "capo". In its first meaning it is the "leader" or "captain" but there seems to be a figurative sense as in this expression: "E un capo classico".

Where does the figurative meaning come from, and in what context can it be used (di vestiario? di musica? ...)

Comment: Do you mean _È un capo classico_ (i.e. “It is a...”)?

Comment: As you can see for instance [here](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capo), _capo_ has lots of possible meanings. Without a context, it's hard to give you a definite answer. As an Italian, I'd guess someone is talking about clothing, but who knows.

Comment: Il senso di capo riferito all’abbigliamento è quelli di unità, pezzo singolo: “*Unità in un insieme di animali o cose: un gregge di duecento capi;  capo di vestiario”* https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/capo.shtml

Comment: “Un capo classico” generally refers to a piece of clothing, classic in style.

Comment: Thanks, I think the links mentioned answered the question, but my Italian is good enough to catch everything: Capo is part of a body? Also what does capo d'anno for example refer to?

Comment: Yes, "capo" means, among other things, "head" and it is from that meaning as "head" that many other meanings stemmed (e.g. "leader", as the head was considered the most important part of the body, or "top/beginning" as the head is the top of the body). "Capo d'anno" refers to the beginning of the year.

Comment: 1- avere dolor, mal di capo; 2- capo di Stato Maggiore; 3- capo di vestiario; 4- in capo al mondo; 5- capo d’acqua; 6- il capo del chiodo, delo spillo; 7- discorso diviso in tre capi; 8-  cosa fatta capo ha; .......